# How to achieve UItextview or UItextfield with bordered text with delete option?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, uitextview

I am working on a project where i have to achieve web like feature for `UITextView` or `UITextField` with separated background on text with delete option. It should look exactly shown in image I have attached. Please help to achieve this. [image]

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
 NSMutableAttributedString * string = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]initWithString:txtString];
            NSArray *words=[txtString componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
     for (NSString *word in words) {
            [txtString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"," withString:@" "]; //if ([word hasSuffix:@","]) {
            self.m_interestsTxtView.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:17];
            self.m_interestsTxtView.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
            NSRange range=[txtString rangeOfString:word];
            [string addAttribute:NSBackgroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor blackColor] range:range];
            [string addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:  [UIColor whiteColor] range:range];
            [self.m_interestsTxtView setAttributedText:string];
    }
```

Comment: There are an infinite many ways to do this. What have you tried?

Comment: Hi WMios why down vote.. I was not able to find the solution so that i posted. Instead you would have helped me to achieve. You may be the intelligent enough to crack this but not every body will be you... Here is what i have tried....

Comment: I didn't down vote you, I wanted to see what you've tried before I offer you a suggestion.

Comment: Sorry ! Please help to achieve i have edited my post i used attributed string but didn't work as expected .

Comment: Simplest way would be creating a UIVIew with a button and a label.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way would be creating a UIView with a button and a label using xib. Another way would be creating a custom view that acts a template for your requirement and add a UILabel to the template. I made this for learning.I hope you can customise this as per your requirement.

Custom UIView class:

```
  - (void)drawRect:(CGRect)frame {

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    UIColor* color = [UIColor colorWithRed: 1 green: 1 blue: 1 alpha: 1];

    UIBezierPath* rectanglePath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect: CGRectMake(CGRectGetMinX(frame), CGRectGetMinY(frame), 82, 36) cornerRadius: 11];
    [color setFill];
    [rectanglePath fill];
    [UIColor.darkGrayColor setStroke];
    rectanglePath.lineWidth = 1;
    [rectanglePath stroke];


    UIBezierPath* ovalPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect: CGRectMake(CGRectGetMinX(frame) + 67, CGRectGetMinY(frame) + 3, 11, 11)];
    [UIColor.redColor setFill];
    [ovalPath fill];

    CGContextSaveGState(context);
    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, CGRectGetMinX(frame) + 71.5, CGRectGetMinY(frame) + 8.5);

    UIBezierPath* bezierPath = UIBezierPath.bezierPath;
    [bezierPath moveToPoint: CGPointMake(-4, 0)];
    [bezierPath addCurveToPoint: CGPointMake(5, 0) controlPoint1: CGPointMake(5, 0) controlPoint2: CGPointMake(5, 0)];
    [UIColor.whiteColor setStroke];
    bezierPath.lineWidth = 1;
    [bezierPath stroke];

    CGContextRestoreGState(context);
}
```

I have added a UILabel 'Egg' to the custom view.

This would give you :

[image]

Add these customViews(I call them as `buttonLabel`) to an array `buttonLabelsArray`

If you want to use the UIButton for showing the X mark, you don't have to manage the touches, but if you don't want to use UIButton, then you should pinpoint the touches.

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    for (UIView *but in buttonLabelsArray) {
        CGPoint locationPoint = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:but];
        if (CGRectContainsPoint(but.bounds, [touches.anyObject  locationInView:but])==YES){
            if ( (locationPoint.x>=64 && locationPoint.x<=80)
                &&  (locationPoint.y>=3  && locationPoint.y<=12) ) {

                NSLog(@"pressed close button");
                [but removeFromSuperview]; 

                    //Do something else
            }
        }
    }

}
```

You might have to change the if

```
( (locationPoint.x>=64 && locationPoint.x<=80)
                    &&  (locationPoint.y>=3  && locationPoint.y<=12) )
```

condition based on your custom view frame.